# Turn off snippets in mavericks

Tags: osx-mavericks, snippets

A new feature in Mavericks in text expansion snippets. These are syncing from from my iPhone. Is there a way to turn them off in Mavericks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an iPhone, but can't you just remove all replacements from System Preferences?

[image]

If that doesn't work or if you want to keep the replacements, try to uncheck Edit > Substitutions > Text Replacement, or run a command like this:

`for d in $(defaults domains|tr -d ,);do osascript -e "app id \"$d\""&>/dev/null&&defaults write $d TextReplacement -bool false;done`

Comment: Where are these located: Edit > Substitutions > Text Replacement?

Comment: Many applications like Safari and TextEdit have that option in the menu bar. For example Chrome doesn't have that option, but it also doesn't support text replacement.

Comment: Do you know how I can stop the snippets syncing between my iPhone and Mac?